# Geometry problem - proving atleast three lines are concurrent!

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction, quadrilateral

> Each of the given $9$ lines cuts a given square into two quadrilateral,whose areas are in ratio $2:3$. Prove that at least three of these lines pass through the same point.

how to approach this question I tried by making possible combinations but didn't seem to get anything helpful. Can anyone prove this rigourously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the square's vertices at $(\pm1,\pm1)$. Since each line splits the square into two quadrilaterals, they individually cut the square at opposite sides. It is then rather easy to show that such a line must pass through one of the four points $(0,\pm4/5),(\pm4/5,0)$ (otherwise they do not partition the area in a $2:3$ ratio). By the pigeonhole principle ($9$ pigeons, $4$ holes), one of those four points must be incident to three different lines.

Comment: Ok but I didn't know about pigeonhole principle. I will read about it. Is it possible to prove without that? Also this principle is not in my syllabus.

Comment: @SMSheikh No; the pigeonhole principle is cleverly hidden in the problem's parameters. If there had been $8$ lines, the result would not have held in all cases.

Comment: Can we prove this for general without assuming specific points?

Comment: @SMSheikh I fixed thw square's coordinates without loss of generality. So my proof is still correct even withiut fixing points.